# How to view uploaded pictures in jade

Tags: image, node.js, express, mongoose, pug

I was wondering how to view an uploaded picture in jade here are some of my code sample's below

Uploading The Image

```
 app.post('/add', function (req, res, next) {
   var person = new Person({
     image: './public/images/' + req.files.person.image.name;
   });

   var tmp_path = req.files.person.image.path;
   var target_path = './public/images/' + req.files.person.image.name;

   fs.rename(tmp_path, target_path, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      return next(new Error(err));
    }

    fs.unlink(tmp_path, function (err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }

      person.save(function (err) {
        if (err) {
          return next(new Error(err.message));
        }

        res.redirect('/view/' + person._id);
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Person View Page

```
app.get('/view/:id', function (req, res, next) {
  Person.findById(req.params.id, function (err, person) {
    if (err) {
      return next(new Error(err));
    }

    if (!person) {
      return next(new Error('Invalid reference to person information'));
    }

    fs.readFile(person.image, 'binary', function (err, file) {
      if (err) {
        return next(new Error(err));
      } else {
        res.render(path + 'view', {
          title: title,
          person: person,
          file: file
        });
      }
    });
  });
});
```

And in my view.jade I use to display the picture

```
img(src='#{file}')
```

But its not being displayed,SOMEONE PLEASE HELP ME !!

Answer (score 0):

treat `file` as a javascript variable inside the parens

```
img(src=file)
```

Comment: I have good results with jade and is what I use most often. Some people don't like the syntax but for me it is good

Comment: No there will be a little amount of overhead due to jade's rendering engine. However it is highly unlikely that the jade processing time will impact your application in any significant way. If my original answer is acceptable could you please accept it?

Answer (score 0):

you can try img(src='#{locals.file}')

Comment: in view.jade the locals prefix is missing to .file. I have added that and lets see if that helps

Answer (score 0):

This code Worked for me to display the image With Jade.

```
 .image-block
      h2 
      img(src="/image.jpg" alt="image not found")
```

or

```
img(src="/#{pathTOImage}" alt="image not found")
```

And in pug you have to write the code like this:

```
img(src="/" + pathTOImage)
```